# Azure - Splitting up a react app using Azure CDN Endpoints

Tags: reactjs, azure, url-rewriting, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app website, it has multiple pages using react router. I discovered recently I can host my site using Azure Storage Account rather than a web app which is pretty cool.

The main content of this website is a list of games which when clicked opens a list of characters per game. Each game has a path, my intention is to stick each of these game paths on a seperate custom domain to give the appearance that they are each their own site.

I am attempting to do this using azure cdn, and ive recently discovered that i can use Azure CDN to create endpoints and allocate them each a custom domain.

So I have a CDN Profile with Verizon Premium

[image]

I have a primary endpoint called [website-name]-cdn, it uses the base hostname with no origin path. Loads the base website as expected.

[image]

I have another endpoint called [website-name]-dota-2, it has the origin path for the game dota 2. Loads the base website instead of the page for dota 2, I need this to go straight to the dota 2 page.

[image]

Here is my url rewrite rule.

[image]

I want to be able to set up an endpoint for each individual game, but i just cant seem to configure things properly to get the urls to load correctly.
Everytime I change the rule I have to wait 4 hours so progress is slow.

Any help is much appreciated :)
Hopefully this is better layed out that my last attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.

In short, the answer is that this cannot be easily accomplished the way I was going about it. However changing things wasn't as bad as I thought it would be.

The best way to accomplish this is to change the site to have multiple entry points, this cannot be accomplished out of the box with CRA so [you need to use something like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewire-multiple-entry). With my multi-entry point react site I change the react-router routes based on the entry point of the site.
Once this is done you can deploy the site to multiple storage containers, and then in each one specify a different entry point.